# Xamarin Sqlite-pcl library problems

Tags: sqlite, xamarin

I try to make a app and work with `sqlite-pcl` and got the following error when my app starts;

```
DllImport attempting to load: 'e_sqlite3'.
DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/appTecnicos.appTecnicos/files/.__override__/libe_sqlite3': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/appTecnicos.appTecnicos-1/lib/x86//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/appTecnicos.appTecnicos/files/.__override__/libe_sqlite3" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/appTecnicos.appTecnicos/files/.__override__/libe_sqlite3.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/appTecnicos.appTecnicos-1/lib/x86//storage/emulated/0/Android/data/appTecnicos.appTecnicos/files/.__override__/libe_sqlite3.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libe_sqlite3': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/appTecnicos.appTecnicos-1/lib/x86//system/lib/libe_sqlite3" not found'.
DllImport error loading library '/system/lib/libe_sqlite3.so': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/appTecnicos.appTecnicos-1/lib/x86//system/lib/libe_sqlite3.so" not found'.
DllImport error loading library 'libe_sqlite3': 'dlopen failed: library "/data/app/appTecnicos.appTecnicos-1/lib/x86/libe_sqlite3" not found'.
DllImport loaded library 'libe_sqlite3.so'.
DllImport searching in: 'e_sqlite3' ('libe_sqlite3.so').
Searching for 'sqlite3_libversion_number'.
An unhandled exception occured.
```

I installed the nuget package in both solutions, portable and droid. I installed the `Sqlite` component in droid project.

I cleaned the build and recompiled but it returned the same error.

EDIT:

I found this on my Compiler debug;

```
Loaded assembly: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/appTecnicos.appTecnicos/files/.__override__/SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.dll
```

Its seems like the e_sqlite3.dll its already on the proyect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add a link to the specific package you downloaded?

Answer (score 1):

The "DllImport error loading library '.../.**override**/libe_sqlite3'" message has been misleading to me as well. The debug output was just coinciding with the actual exception that froze my app.

For me, it was using a relative path in the `new SQLiteConnection()` -- which was working perfectly fine before with the UWP version. After I changed it to use an absolute path, it also worked on Android:

```
var dbpath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "myData.sqlite");
db = new SQLiteConnection(dbpath, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think  that the package has not been correctly installed on your starting app. Remove `sqlite-pcl`, clean, rebuild & install it to your starting app and droid project. Also check your references to see if its really there.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. I got a class like;

```
public class StaticsValues
{
    [...]
    public static string FOLDERPATH;
    public static string DBPATH;
    public static BD.BDManager BDMANAGER = new BD.BDManager;
}
```

And the object `BDManager` start in the solution before my DROID project compiled. I change to:

```
public class StaticsValues
{
    [...]
    public static string FOLDERPATH;
    public static string DBPATH;
    public static BD.BDManager BDMANAGER ;
}
```

And start `BD.Manager` in `App.cs` and now works.